# How can I fix ES6 Eslint errors while trying to return a ternary operator in arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, ternary-operator

I understand that `() => {}` does not need return, however if it is not there then `Eslint` complains about unused expressions.

```
export const isInInterval = (from, to, target) => {
  if (isNaN(Date.parse(to)) && isNaN(Date.parse(from)) === true) {
    return
  }
  const toUnixTimestamp = time => new Date(time).getTime()
  toUnixTimestamp(to) - target > toUnixTimestamp(from) ? true : false
}
```

Here is the function: it tries to find out whether some specified date(`to`) minus specified period(`target`) is later in time than `from`. It should return true if so and false in the opposite case.
I keep bumping into eslint error `expected assignment to a function call and instead saw expression`.

I tried to rewrite it several times, but in most iterations I got `arrow function expects no return error, ex.:

return (toUnixTimestamp(to) - target > toUnixTimestamp(from)) ? true : false

Comment: It is difficult to see what is happening because your code is too compact! I would add more intermediate variables to better see what is happening. Short compact one liners do not improve code readability. Dumb plain obvious code improves readability.

Comment: Per @givanse's comment, you might consider a function like `isDateValid` and then your first line can be `if (!isDateValid(to) || !isDateValid(from)) return;`

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that () => {} does not need return

That's not the case. Arrow functions only implicitly return when what followed the `=>` is a *single expression*. If you use `=> {`, the opening bracket `{` indicates the start of a function block, and you do indeed need to explicitly `return` at the end of the block (or wherever else you want to `return` something).

At the moment, your code isn't returning anything at all - that's what the linting error is trying to tell you - the `true : false` is going unused at the moment, it's just an orphaned expression.

So, just add the `return` statement to the beginning of your conditional:

```
export const isInInterval = (from, to, target) => {
  if (isNaN(Date.parse(to)) && isNaN(Date.parse(from)) === true) {
    return
  }
  const toUnixTimestamp = time => new Date(time).getTime()
  return toUnixTimestamp(to) - target > toUnixTimestamp(from)
    ? true
    : false
}
```

Or, because `>` evaluates to a `boolean` already, you might omit the conditional operator entirely:

```
return toUnixTimestamp(to) - target > toUnixTimestamp(from)
```

Here's an example of how you would write an arrow function that *does* use implicit return:

```
export const isEarlyTimestamp = (timestamp) => (
  timestamp < 4000000
  ? true
  : false
);
```

Comment: thank you CertainPerformance, eslint screams at me again with `arrow function expected no return value`, I guess I will just ignore the line with eslint-disable-line.

Comment: The rule that's tripping you up is probably `consistent-return`: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/consistent-return If you like implicit return when possible (which I think is just fine - it significantly reduces syntax noise, especially with array methods), just disable that rule.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
export const isInInterval = (from, to, target) => {
    if (isNaN(Date.parse(to)) && isNaN(Date.parse(from)) === true) {
    return false
    }
    const toUnixTimestamp = time => new Date(time).getTime()
    return toUnixTimestamp(to) - target > toUnixTimestamp(from);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tilak, I thought of it as well, unfortunately I still got `[eslint] Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression. (no-unneeded-ternary)`.

Comment: Okay, do one thing. write a if condition statement instead of ternary and cheeck once!!

Comment: It did help! Thank you! Though it looks a little bit inelegant, I am wondering whether it can be done better:
    if (toUnixTimestamp(to) - target > toUnixTimestamp(from)) {
        return true
      }
      return false
However it is the only way that works with eslint from all the proposed solutions. Thank you

Comment: Same, error on `true`: [eslint] Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression. (no-unneeded-ternary), rewrite to if - else helped though.

Comment: Try again, this will be better way!!

Comment: Let us discuss this in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178056/discussion-between-tilak-putta-and-margot

Comment: Thank you for the chat invite, however I need to leave very soon. I saw your solution, it is quite clear, I understood and I like it. Thanks a ton for help!